# How does BigCommerce Stencil Theme Editor bundle @import SCSS files?

Tags: sass, bigcommerce

When I use an @import statement that imports from a node modules folder, the import works perfectly.

`@import "../../node_modules/bulma-scss/scss/utilities/functions";`

However once a user goes to edit the theme via the backoffice theme editor and saves the changes, there is an error basically saying that that node_modules folder does not exist.

**Expected Result**

Editing a .scss file via the backoffice editor and 'save and apply' would successfully update the corresponding .css file used in the theme

**Actual Result** - https://www.screencast.com/t/RluUCmMq7Iqa

A string of 'file doesn't exist' errors occurs as the "@import" statements reference files used in the node modules folder

Video of issue explained: 1min 40s https://www.screencast.com/t/D4CvGQkk0cl

Answer (score 0):

`node_modules` are available in the theme, but are not available when editing in the browser. The reason for this is that during "bundling", the contents of `node_modules` is converted into a different format and placed inside the `/parsed` directory.

When editing a theme in the control panel of a store, the contents of the `/parsed` directory/`node_modules` is not available to edit and not otherwise accessible.

I would recommend including the file through a non-package manage method in order to address this.

Comment: Thank you for that information, that makes sense. The reason we did an import as described is because this was an existing pattern used in the Cornerstone theme. Check this link: https://github.com/bigcommerce/cornerstone/blob/master/assets/scss/components/vendor/slick/_component.scss


Are there any examples of ways to import in vendor stylesheets without having to do weird copy/paste with webpack?

Comment: @Ransom I believe that was included with the expectation it wouldn't be altered (at least not from within the CP as that feature wasn't released yet when that import statement was added). I don't know of a better way :(